# How to accept all xmpp buddy requests and save it in roster?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I use that code to accept all buddy requests and add that users to roster list

```
//auto accept friend
NSXMLElement *mypresence = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
[mypresence addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"subscribed"];
[mypresence addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[presence fromStr]];
[mypresence addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[WebRequests sharedInstance].sourceUser.uJid];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:mypresence];
```

But if someone from that users delete current user from their roster - that users deletes from current roster list. How to add users to current roster list without case that this user can delete yourself?